# Do not reset session after each it block when running rspec tests via sauce labs

Tags: rspec, capybara, saucelabs

For faster testing and to have access to a greater number of devices I wish to run my rspec capybara tests via sauce labs. However I am having problems running the it blocks in rspec sequentially.I generally test different functionality of pages in different it blocks as shown below:

```
describe 'website ordering' do

  it 'should have items listed on page' do
   // test steps to check if item is on page

  end

  it 'should be able to add item to shopping cart'
   // test steps to add items to cart

  end

end
```

When I run tests locally on my browser this works. The browser windows stays opens and the tests follow from it block to it block without any issues. But via sauce labs it seems to reset the session after each it block and as such my tests fails. I have tried to monkey-patch the reset session method using this:

```
module Capybara
    def self.reset_sessions!
      # Do nothing
    end
end
```

But this does not seem to have any affect. I don't want to re-write my entire test suite so that there is only 1 test per spec file, have over 600 tests so not really feasible! Has anyone encountered this problem and if so how did you deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so contacted sauce labs about this. Turns out it is the way their platform is setup, after each block they it block they rest the session. Will have to investigate some workarounds for this or else change how my tests are setup.

Comment: To clarify: It's how the Sauce gem is set up; Customers can still write their own integration to use Sauce Labs' platform in any manner they choose (although we recommend not having order-dependent tests).